# Extracting (searching in) a subset of a dictionary?

Tags: php, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary (or list) that is a subset of another dictionary in PHP. Please look below at my code written in Python:

```python
ThePythons = {
    'GC': 'Graham Chapman',
    'JC': 'John Cleese',
    'EI': 'Eric Idle',
    'MP': 'Michael Palin'
}

query = ['EI', 'JC']

output = [[item,ThePythons[item]] for item in query if item in ThePythons]
print(output)
```

And output is:

```
[['EI', 'Eric Idle'], ['JC', 'John Cleese']]
```

I don't know how to accomplish the same functionality in in PHP. Please give me the corresponding code in PHP. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @RPM I know. There is Python code because I don't know PHP at all. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<?php

$thePythons = array(
    'GC' => 'Graham Chapman',
    'JC' => 'John Cleese',
    'EI' => 'Eric Idle',
    'MP' => 'Michael Palin'
);

$query = array(0 => 'EI', 1 => 'JC');

$resultList = array();

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($query); $i++) {
    $resultList[$i] = array($query[$i] => $thePythons[$query[$i]]);
}

var_dump($resultList);

?>
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["EI"]=>
    string(9) "Eric Idle"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["JC"]=>
    string(11) "John Cleese"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :-) I'll check it tomorrow because now I do not have PHP interpreter.

Comment: @Scottie You're welcome. You can check/verify the output of the script here: http://ideone.com/TPZeTu (scroll down to where it says "stdout").

Comment: @Scottie Any luck trying out my solution? I'd be happy to improve my answer if you found that there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, everything fine and working as I expected! :) Many thanks for your help. Have a great day! :)